# What is the pip command used in robot framework to install String library

Tags: robotframework

could someone please help me with the pip command used to install string library in Robotframework?

Comment: The String library is installed with robot framework - you can't have one without the other. If you are getting an error, please show the exact and complete error in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not needed, however you do need to activate it using `Library   String`. The [Robot Framework Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/) contains all the information you need. From the specific [String Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) the below example is taken:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${str1} =   Convert To Lowercase    ABC
    ${str2} =   Convert To Lowercase    1A2c3D
    Should Be Equal    ${str1}     abc
    Should Be Equal    ${str2}     1a2c3d
```

Comment: I have used Library  String in settings. But if i use a keyword "fetch from right", Keyword definition not found error is displaying.

Comment: *** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  String

*** Keywords ***
    Click link  ${user_reset_password}
    Sleep  3s
    ${sys_password2}=  get alert message
    ${result}=  Fetch from right  ${sys_password2}  -
    log  ${result}

Comment: Able to use convert to uppercase keyword but not "fetch from right" keyword

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code example. Then you can refer to it from the comments. Also add any error you may see in detail.